# Android WebView(Activity A) music still play even user go to Activity B

Tags: android

I would like to find a solution on how to stop the music when user go back to the *Main* Activity.

My code is below, user can go back to the *Activity A* as usually but the music still play from *Activity B*.

I have the second Activity as the code below:

## Layout A

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Song" />
```

## Java of Activity A

```
public class MySongActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
}
}
```

## Layout B

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="none" />
```

## Java of Activity B

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://m.orkun2u.com/msopheap/song/mysongs.htm");
}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Kindly please help me. I do appreciate for your help.

**Note**:

I tried all the way that Google it but still doesn't stop the music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just one more thing about what Padma Kumar said. the way to stop is to use the `dismiss` function.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mWebView.destroy();
    super.onPause();
}
```

*updated:* chenged the function from `dismiss()` to `destroy()`, for more: read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Dear Thepoosh, thank you so much, but after i added your code in WebViewActivity it's said The method dismiss() is underfined. Didn't work.

Comment: oh, sorry, it's not `dismiss` but `close()`

Comment: Dear Thepoosh. It's appear same. The method close() is underfined for WebView.

Comment: @user1377695, sorry again, fixed

Comment: Dear Thepoosh, It's work..I really thank you very much for help me on this that I took almost a week but you just help me for a minutes. Thanks you gain.

Comment: pleasure, let me suggest going back to your other question and accepting some of them, It will draw more people to answer your questions

Comment: Dear Thepoosh, I am sorry to disturb you again. You script is working well now.. But i just know that when I push Home button the music also gone, Actually I want music still play if user push Home Button and destroy the music when user push Back Button. Please help me sir.

Comment: try instead of overriding the `onPause` method, overriding the `onDestroy` one, this should do the trick

Comment: One more thing the WebView also GONE and blank page when I turn back to the WebView :(

Answer (score 0):

//onPause stop your music

```
   public class MySongActivity extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Context context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    //stop the music here
}
```

}

Comment: Dear Kumar, I already added if // stop the music 
            player.stop(); but the music still play in previouse activity.

Answer (score 0):

I just think the best way to deal this trouble is not `webView.destory()` in Activity's `onPause()`.

I think that:

```
@Override  
protected void onResume() {  
    super.onResume();  
    webView.resumeTimers();  
    webView.onResume();
}

@Override  
protected void onPause() {  
    if (null != getWebView()) {  
        webView.pauseTimers();  
        webView.onPause();  
        webView.reload();  
    }  
    super.onPause();  
}
```

Do my best.